# Sync Visual Studio Preferences

Tags: visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sync Settings between computers in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2907739/sync-settings-between-computers-in-visual-studio-2010)

I know it's possible to export/import settings for VS, but is there any service for syncing them across machines?

Answer (score 0):

This might help, it is a way to use dropbox to sync settings and extensions via the cloud:

http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/Sync-Your-Visual-Studio-Environment-Through-THE-CLOUD.aspx